# why is viewdidunload function not called when i click back button on navigation based app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hi I want to release my `fetchedResultsController`.

I was wondering why is `viewdidunload` not called when i push back button on navigation based application.or i should release it somewhere else?

thanks for help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`-viewDidUnload` is only guaranteed to be called when the view is purged from memory, and the UIKit framework might be hanging on to it in order to present the view quickly if the user goes back there. To deterministically release your fetched result controller when the view disappears, use `-viewWillDisappear:` or `-viewDidDisappear:`.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer i vote it up, i try it and then accept,thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you think that you're having leaks because viewDidLoad isn't called, than check your controller.view removeFromSuperView calls and ensure that you're using removeFromParentViewController. Instead of just removing the view from superview remove your viewController from its parentController.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing something strange happening in my case: `dealloc` is called but `viewDidUnload` don't.

But I think I can live with that for memory management purposes because all my strong properties will be deallocated at that time (I'm using ARC).

In your case I think you should check also for `dealloc` being called and release your `fetchedResultsController` there.

Answer (score -1):

you can call it yourself from `-dealloc`.

Comment: is there one valid reason to do so?

Comment: Wrong, dealloc isn't guaranteed to be called either! thats why, is there any valid reason?